# Can Jenkins pipeline use variables in agent stage?

Tags: pip, jenkins-pipeline, tox

Problem
I'm using Jenkins pipeline and testing python with tox.
This combination explodes when tox creates a python virtualenv with a pip
whose shebang line exceeds the hard coded system imposed maximum of 127 characters.

To set a shorter workspace location,I want to add:

```
agent {
    node {
        label 'debian-slave'
        customWorkspace "workspace/${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
    }
}
```

but env.GIT_BRANCH is not yet defined. environment has not yet been calculated when the agent block runs.

How can I add the branch number or something similar to the workdir definition?

I don't want to lose the per-branch unique workspaces.

What Jenkins variables exist at the "agent" stage?

Comment: fwiw - https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/pull/794 was just merged, which will help with working aroun that limitation.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but a tox (or venv) fix could definitely solve the problem. Thanks!